# Two-Legged OAuth and Private API?

Tags: ios, security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I recently read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846752/simple-secure-api-authentication-system) about a simple, secure API authentication system and see that 2-legged OAuth is a good solution to go with. But say I am just creating my own iPhone app, and would like it to interface with my own private API. Is 2-legged OAuth appropriate in this situation? Are there any disadvantages to taking this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the user of the iphone client logging in with someone or are you just trying to authenticate the client ?

If the former, then use oauth and have the user log in to some openid provider. Its actually what that is meant for.

If the later ( and it sounds like this is what you are doing), just create some secret and append it as a get request to everything and operate over https. It sounds insecure, but anything else you do will be just as bad. Any crypto/w/e solution you make will involve baking a secret into your code. If someone grabs that secret ( via say a decompiler) then they can fake w/e system you use anyway.